# $f(x,y,z) = \log(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz)$. Find $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z})^2 f$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y,z) = \log(x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz)$ then to find the value of $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^2 f$.

We can do it by brute force and lengthy process ...is there any elegant method?

Will Euler's Theorem for homogeneous equation come to help us!

Comment: Standard notation for partial derivatives is $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f$, not $\displaystyle\frac{\delta}{\delta x} f$.  I changed it. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Omitting the point of application, we have $e^{f} = x^3+y^2+z^3-3xyz$. Applying $(\partial_x+\partial_y+\partial_z)$ on both sides we get: $$e^f(\partial_x+\partial_y+\partial_z)f = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2 - xz-yz-xy)$$Repeating, we get: $$e^f((\partial_x+\partial_y+\partial_z)f)^2 + e^f(\partial_x+\partial_y+\partial_z)^2f = 0,$$so: $$(\partial_x+\partial_y+\partial_z)^2f = - ((\partial_x+\partial_y+\partial_z)f)^2 = -\left(\frac{3(x^2+y^2+z^2 - xz-yz-xy)}{x^3+y^2+z^3-3xyz}\right)^2$$